# Using variable with sed

Tags: bash, sed

First of all i apologise in case this has been answered before but i couldn't solve my problem.

I need to search a pattern and then replace it with a line of text comprising of both text and variable.Btw i am using bash..

say

```
$var = "stacko.ver/rulz=" **Note: $var contain double quotes & = & a dot and /**
```

i want to so the follow
1.Search for `;te.xt =`   **Note: The value to be search contain ; & =  and a dot**

2.Replace it with

```
textnum=$var
```

Of course $var should be replaced with its actual value

My attempts

```
sed -i "s/;te.xt =/textnum=$var/" file
sed -i "s/;te.xt =/textnum="$var"/" file
sed -i "s/";te.xt ="/"textnum=$var"/" file
```

None of these actually worked , either sed giving me an error or the value of $var not shown in file

Thanks for the help

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting doesn't help since this is a sed issue, not a bash issue. Just pick a sed s-expression delimiter that doesn't appear in your text:

```
sed -i "s|;te.xt =|textnum=$var|" file
```

You can pick any delimiter for `s` that doesn't appear in your input. `sed -e 'streetlight'` is a perfectly valid sed command.

Answer (score 3):

I can see the error:

```
$ var="stacko.ver/rulz="
$ data="foo ;te.xt = bar"
$ sed "s/;te.xt =/textnum=$var/" <<< "$data"
sed: -e expression #1, char 31: unknown option to `s'
```

The problem is that `$var` contains a slash, so sed's `s///` command is breaking. You need to pick a character that does not appear in $var

```
$ sed "s#;te.xt =#textnum=$var#" <<< "$data"
foo textnum=stacko.ver/rulz= bar
```

This can be hard -- what if slash and hash are in $var? Using bash, you can use [ANSI-C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) to use a control character that is unlikely to appear in your data, e.g.

```
$ sed $'s\037;te.xt =\037textnum=$var\037' <<< "$data"
foo textnum=stacko.ver/rulz= bar
```